# Python + Django + Cordova: Reading set-cookie header in Android

Tags: android, django, python-2.7, cordova, cookies

I'm using `Python2.7` And `Django==1.7` on the ServerSide and `Cordova==5.3.3` for Mobile ClientSide.

In ClientSide, I've used cookie-base authentication in iOS properly but seemingly Android doesn't support cookies for `Cordova` based on the documentation.

As you know i can access user's sessionId via cookie in django as below:

```
def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
```

But in this case maybe i need to access cookie manually because of `Cordova` limitation.

So my questions are:

- Is the any way to access cookie header in `Cordova-Android`?
- If there is not, Whats the best way to get sessionId instead of set-cookie header? custom header or get parameters?
- And finally whats the best way to get and validate sessionId manually from session_table of django for current user?

Thanks.